# Debug stop working after update android studio to Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3 - Application is waiting for the debugger to attach

Tags: android-studio

When I try to debug ***any app*** on ***an emulator or a device*** I got the next message:

> *Application is waiting for the debugger to attach*

so I can not debug my app. I tried many solutions but to no avail.

OS: Windows 10 x64

Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3

Devices I used has: android 5 & android 10

Emulator I used has: android 6

Thanks